# Configure Django along with Apache

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7

8 Years ago I used to work perfectly on a PHP projects where is running a new website is slightly very simple and easy, just copy your files, create virtual host & run your website.

A while I was involved somehow to create a project using Python, so some digging I found that Django is the most proper framework, searching again for how to running the Django application to start developing, and I follow some tutorials on youtube & I found the following:

[note: my working environments are Mac osx 10.10, Ubuntu 14.04]

1. python integrated on both of my os
2. I have to install PIP [install easy_install first]
3. Install virtualenv
4. creating new virtualenv & activating it.
5. Installing Django using PIP
6. Start Django & run server then I have to get the IP [127.0.0.1:8000]

after all of this I have to follow the tutorials to start developing, but I am stacked with some questions where is:

1. How could I use apache + mod_wsgi to create virtual host for my django sites as I am used to do using MAMP PRO or built in apache on UBUNTO, so I found it a bit difficult to manage multiple django sites on my development environment.
2. How should the production server configured to run my django website, as I will also the administrator of RedHat
3. I know that I am a bit confused from the difference way Python should work with.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation, where all of this is fully explained?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know how to create virtual hosts, so you know how to serve several sites.

Below there's a template for a virtual host running a wsgi object - the one you'll find in the django project.

It has an alias for my static folder which I called "public" and links to the actual folder "static".

On settings.py

```
# The static alias
STATIC_URL = '/public/'
# The actual static folder
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
```

Just make sure that the apache user "www-data" has access and writing permissions on folders that you might use, like "media" to upload files.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess yourproject  display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup yourproject

    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/youproject/src/
    ServerName youproject.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/youproject.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/youproject_access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/public_html/youproject/src/project/wsgi.py
    <Directory "/var/www/public_html/youproject/src/project/">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Allow from all
            Order deny,allow
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /public /var/www/public_html/youproject/src/static
    <Directory /var/www/public_html/youproject/src/static>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can run a django project with the above, but if you want to have different packages on the server, you may want to consider running a virtualenv on each project and pass that env to the wsgi.

This way you can use independent packages for each project.

Folder structure example:

```
-env (virtualenv)
-src (django files)
---- project
----- ----- settings
----- ----- ----- production.py
----- ----- ----- development.py
----- ----- ----- default.py
----- ----- wsgi.py
----- ----- urls.py
---- apps (Your apps)
---- static
---- media
---- manage.py
```

django wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Setting python paths
project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
git_path = os.path.dirname(project_path)

# Adding the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
virtual_env_path = os.path.join(git_path, 'env')
virtual_env_lib_path = os.path.join(virtual_env_path, 'lib', 'python2.7', 'site-packages')

# Adding the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir(virtual_env_path)

# Adding directories to PYTHON PATH
sys.path.append(project_path)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(project_path, 'project'))

# Choosing which settings the project will use - production / development
# from project.config import server
# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", server.DJANGO_SETTINGS)

# Lets just select the production settings for now
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'project.settings.production')

# Activating virtual env
activate_env = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(virtual_env_path, 'bin', 'activate_this.py'))
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If you check above, there's a commented part to choose the settings.py file.

I usually run 2 files - production and development , so you might want to consider that too.

Comment: I would like first to know how to install mod_wsgi on MAMP Pro & ubuntu 14.04, as I know it's the supported module for running python projects on apache

Comment: for ubuntu, you can do it easilly with "sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi"

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-12-04